# Configuring TextMate to add empty scroll-space at bottom of document view?

Tags: textmate

I've been using BBEdit for years, but I've just started using TextMate because I find it has better support for Ruby on Rails than BBEdit (please don't start a flame-war over this!).

One thing I really miss is that BBEdit can add 1/2 or 1/1 page of empty space below the document (without adding lines to the actual document). This means that I will never have to write code at the very bottom of the window/screen, but I can always scroll the page to get the current line at a comfortable hight on the screen, even if it is the last line in the document.

Now, this might seem minor, but after using TextMate for a few days, missing this feature is really starting to bug me.

On the off chance that there is a setting I missed, or that there is a plugin or something out there, I thought I'd throw the question out here. If you know of any way to replicate this behaviour in TextMate, please share!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be rather a late answer but i am posting b/c this question is high in google. Looking for the same issue i found:

PageFeed

PageFeed is a TextMate plugin that allows one to scroll past the last line of a document.

Its not perfect but for most cases its all you need: https://github.com/ampt/PageFeed

Answer (score 15):

There is now an [option in TextMate 2](https://github.com/textmate/textmate/pull/778) to scroll past the end of the document.

[image]

Comment: My life became just slightly more tolerable. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I've ever witnessed a flame war involving BBEdit.

No, TextMate doesn't allow that.

You could create a macro/snippet to add a bunch of `\n` at the bottom of the file.

Vim, Emacs and Sublime Text all allow this and have better RoR support than BBEdit.

Comment: Hmm... I wouldn't want to leave loads of new-lines in the files when I close them, but if it's possible to automatically add lines on open and remove them again on close, that might be workable. On the other hand, cmd-down_arrow won't put you at the actual end of the document in that case. Might be a minor problem though... I'll leave the question open for a while in case someone else has something to pitch in. Otherwise I'll give it to you.

Comment: No problem, I've been using TM for years but I've never heard of any way to do that without actually adding lines. AFAIK it has been requested many times in the past but it never received a proper answer from Allan. After a long silence someone at Macromates has posted news a month or so ago about an upcoming alpha of TM2 before the end of the year, maybe this feature will be available or in the TODO list. In the mean time, since you are just starting out with TM you may want to look around for better/more alive editors before you commit to it.

Answer (score 0):

Lacking a scrolling margin, especially at the bottom, when searching in text, is the most frustraing thing in Notepad, Word, Excel, etc. and is enough by itself to make me hate the products on almost a daily basis.  EDT, TPU, etc, were great text editors which had this feature (maybe they introduced it) and, now that I've found Emacs emulates them, I use it all the time, and text editing life is good again.  I can't understand how most of the world accepts the crazy situation of using a text editor that is worse than those in vogue 20 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

For those who aren't clear about the concept or benefits of a scrolling bottom margin, it is not just about adding empty space below the document, but it also lets you see the context of text found in a search.  Without a scrolling margin, the cursor is almost invariably positioned at the bottom line of the screen on the item found, and then to see what comes next you have to manually scroll further down.  With a scrolling margin, the cursor and found text are repositioned above the bottom of the screen by the margin amount, letting you see the found text and all the text surrounding it.  With repeated searches of the same text, this is a huge timesaver.